# Slow waiting bug? (Xbox 360)

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When I press A to wait it takes 30 seconds to actually start waiting. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: The "A" key isn't default to waiting.  It's default to strafe left.  Did you double bound the key manually?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you're pressing A? It isn't the default key for waiting as Nelson said. You need to press it once.